# F# `Map` algorithm

Tags: f#, tree, binary-search-tree

What's the algorithm used for the balanced search tree implementation behind F#'s `Map` type?

https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/FSharp.Core/map.fs

I had guessed it might be an AVL tree but I noticed parts of the code look like `if t2h > t1h + tolerance then` where `let tolerance = 2`. I haven't read though the code but if it were an AVL tree, I'd expect the tolerance `= 1`.

Interestingly, OCaml's LGPL-licensed `Map` module also has codes like `if hl > hr + 2 then begin`: https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/map.ml

Comment: It's an AVL tree.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is technically a height-balanced tree and not an AVL tree, as the height difference can be more than 1.